# useEffect updates it's own dependency causing infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My component displays a table with users. The users are loaded (`getOverviewCitizensToday()`) into redux state and passed as component as a prop (`mapStateToProps`). To request the list of users I need to specify `offset` (`users.length`) so my useEffect needs `users` as a dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData(): Promise<void> {
      const query: NewOverviewServiceUserQueryParameters = {
        offset: users.length,
        sort: transformSortingParams(sorting.order, sorting.orderBy) || undefined,
      }
      await getOverviewCitizensToday(query)
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [getOverviewCitizensToday, sorting.order, sorting.orderBy, users.length])
```

This causes an infinite loop because `getOverviewCitizensToday()` updates users which causes useEffect to re-run...

What's the best way to avoid this infinite loop?

Comment: Do you want your effect to execute only on component mount?

Comment: why do you have fetchData as a dependency in the useEffect?

Comment: I want the effect to execute every time sorting (order/orderBy) is changed. That should trigger a re-fetch from api which updates `users` which triggers re-fetch...

Comment: Sorry @JonathanAkweteyOkine code was incorrect, I updated it

Comment: Can you post what `getOverviewCitizensToday` looks like?

Comment: @olefrank, i am not sure if i understand your question, but you can create another  `useEffect` where you can use as dependency only that variable that should trigger your useEffect.

Comment: @AskMen can you post an example of what you mean? I don't see how I can avoid specifying users as dependency in useEffects

Comment: @olefrank, for example you have to fetch user depending by `users.length`, so you can create: `useEffect(() =>your code , [users.length])`, also you can create another `useEffect(() =>your code , [admins.length])`, where you fetch all admins from the server. The idea, is that is not obligatory to create just one  `useEffect()` for all asynchronous actions, you can split the logic in different functions.

Comment: @AskMen but if fetchUsers() updates users then I enter a infinite loop `useEffect(() => fetchUsers() , [users.length])`

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData(): Promise<void> {
      console.log('fetch')

      const query: NewOverviewServiceUserQueryParameters = {
        offset: users.length,
        sort: transformSortingParams(sorting.order, sorting.orderBy) || undefined,
      }
      await getOverviewCitizensToday(query)
    }
    fetchData()

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [sorting.order, sorting.orderBy])
```

I've had similar scenarios where I want it to execute on certain dependencies only but `useEffect` is wary of the other variables that it is using. The extra comment will remove the warning, even though I know this is not the best practice.

Comment: I would like to learn how to use react-hooks correctly instead, but thanks anyway...